# Drawable changes when in different folder

Tags: android, screen, drawable

I am using a 100x100 pixel image to display something on the only device I support, the 3.2" 240x320 pixel LG E430. I found some strange behaviour though. If I put that image in the `drawable-ldpi` folder, it will be rendered larger than when I put it in my `drawable` folder.

Is this intended? And if so, how should I scale my images so they get rendered correctly, but still can reside in the `drawable-ldpi` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting image in `drawable` folder should be treated as `drawable-mdpi`, that's why if you put your image in `drawable-ldpi` it would be larger.

**Edit:**

In order to put the image in `drawable-ldpi` and having the same size as it was put in `drawable`, scale the original image from 100 x 100 to 75 x 75.

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

Comment: On "correct": when I put them in `drawable` they are correct. But I want them in `drawable-ldpi`; how to scale them then?

Comment: I am not sure why you insist to put them in `drawable-ldpi`, if you really want so, then you should manually scale down your image and put in in `drawable-ldpi`. Let me check to confirm the size to scale to.

Comment: Because the device I support is `ldpi`, when in the future I can support more devices, I don't want to clutter the folders. I already ran into different sized icons and jumbled layouts. It is both learning how thoses folders work as trying to keep my code tree free of unneccessary files.

Comment: Ic. You should scale the image from 100x100 to 75x75. The image should be scaled according to the dpi. FYR I have added that to my answer.